# ngx-ui-loader: loaderId "master" does not exist

Tags: angular, typescript, loader, ngx-ui-loader

In my Angular 8 application, I'm using [ngx-ui-loader](https://tdev.app/ngx-ui-loader) for multiple loaders.
I keep getting error, **loaderId "master" does not exist**. Can anyone help

app.module

```
  const ngxUiLoaderConfig: NgxUiLoaderConfig = {
  fgsColor: '#aeaeae',
  blur: 0,
  fgsPosition: POSITION.centerCenter,
  fgsSize: 50,
  fgsType: SPINNER.fadingCircle,
  hasProgressBar: false,
  overlayColor: "rgba(138,136,136,0)"
  };
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    . .
    NgxUiLoaderModule.forRoot(ngxUiLoaderConfig)
  ]
  })
```

home.module

```
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    . .
    NgxUiLoaderModule
  })
```

home/home.component

```
<router></router>
<ngx-ui-loader></ngx-ui-loader>
```

home/catalogue/catalogue.component

```
<mat-card>
<mat-card-content>
...
...
<ngx-ui-loader [loaderId]="'loader-01'"></ngx-ui-loader>
</mat-card-content>
<mat-card>
<mat-card>
<mat-card-content>
...
...
<ngx-ui-loader [loaderId]="'loader-02'"></ngx-ui-loader>
</mat-card-content>
<mat-card>
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: I dint. I found ngx-spinner easier

Comment: Hi @Pallavi with ngx-spinner we don't have interceptor option? any links would be helpful